# Add an array using HTTP PUT Method in Angular

Tags: angular

I want to add an array in a JSON file (local JSON server) using PUT method in angular:

This is what I have:

newsletter.service:

```js
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private processHttpService: ProcessHTTPService) {

}

setNewsletterEmail(email): Observable<string> {
  console.log('setNewsletterEmail()', JSON.stringify(email));

  return this.http.put<string>(dataURL + 'newsletter', email, httpOptions)
      .pipe(catchError(this.processHttpService.manageError));
}

getNewsletter(): Observable<string[]> {
  return this.http.get<string[]>(dataURL + 'newsletter')
      .pipe(catchError(this.processHttpService.manageError));
}
```

This is my component:

```js
onSubmit() {
  this.email = this.newsLetterForm.value.email;
  console.log(this.newsLetterForm.value.email);
  this.newsLetterForm.reset();

  this.emailRest.push(this.email);
  this.newsletterService.setNewsletterEmail(this.emailRest).subscribe(myEmails => {
    this.email = myEmails;
    console.log("My emails", myEmails);
  });
}
```

`emailRest` is set in the `ngOnInit()` method

```js
return this.newsletterService.getNewsletter().subscribe(myNews => {
  this.emailRest = myNews;
  console.log("My Newsletter", myNews);
});
```

And this is my form:

```html
<form [formGroup]="newsLetterForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <input class="input" type="text" formControlName="email" name="newsletter" placeholder="Enter your email">
    <button class="newsletter-btn"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
</form>
```

Console logs print the array I want to save:

```
["correo@correo.com","correo2@correo2.com"]
```

This is the error:

```
PUT http://localhost:3000/newsletter 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: A 404 not found means that there is no resource on your server for that URL. All the code you posted is irrelevant. You need to modify your server if you want to be able to send it a request to a specific URL, doing a specific thing.

Comment: Of course it has resouces for that URL

Comment: It doesn't, otherwise you wouldn't get a 404. That's what a 404 means. Why don't you show us your server code, which exposes a resource allowing to accept PUT requests on the /newsletter path, on port 3000?

Comment: I'm using json-server (https://github.com/typicode/json-server). I have added objects in other URLs (PUT method) but I don't know why I'm getting that error when I try to add an array.

Comment: Your code shows that you're using a singular route (newsletter, without s). The README explains that singular routes allow getting/updating a singular item (so a single newsletter). Even if it was a plural route and if you had several newsletters identified by an ID, a PUT would be used to update a single of these newsletter, and the correct URL would be /newsletters/42, where 42 would be the ID of the newsletter.. In short, read the README.